# Polyline starts disappearing after zoom out

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I have encountered a strange problem, when i zoom out the my polyline of custom coordinates starts disappearing, following is my code

```
 func setTrackerLines(currentLoc: String, destinationLoc: String) {
        let str1 = currentLoc
        let LocArray1 = str1.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let str2 = destinationLoc
        let LocArray2 = str2.components(separatedBy: ",")

        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (LocArray1[0] as NSString).doubleValue, longitude: (LocArray1[1] as NSString).doubleValue))
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (LocArray2[0] as NSString).doubleValue, longitude: (LocArray2[1] as NSString).doubleValue))

        let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        rectangle.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        rectangle.strokeWidth = 1
        rectangle.map = self.myMapView
    }
}
```

have call this method on viewdidload(), This is how i am using the code

```
  for i in 0 ..< pointArray.count {
        print("Delta: \(delta)")
        if pointArray.count != (i + 1) {
            self.setTrackerLines(currentLoc: pointArray[i], destinationLoc: pointArray[i + 1])

    }
```

The result is showing in pictures. Kindly help please

[image: Polyline Showing]
[image: without polyline at specific zoom level]

Comment: There is nothing wrong here in this code. Please add the rest of it so that we can see everything. Also, it will be better if you can use a `for` loop instead of adding the path manually every time as you are using an array, so it makes more sense to use a `for loop`.

Comment: the above function is called in loop already,

Comment: @SkandarMunir yes, working

Comment: Can you post the fix ?